# Shadowbox + jScrollpane not working?

Tags: jquery, shadowbox, jquery-jscrollpane

Trying to get jScrollpane to work with shadowbox. Not going that well.
Using the iframe option for Shadowbox, it show correct with animation an all, but
the scroll does not get applied. In my iframe I have a div surounding the content
with class="scroll-pane". The code below is within the iframe.

```
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/scrollpane/jquery.mousewheel.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/scrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" href="/scripts/scrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />


        <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery(document).ready(function () {

           $(function () {
               $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
           });
                });
    </script>
```

Comment: jquery probably isn't loading since you're starting with '//ajax'...

Answer (score 0):

This is bug with jquery 1.8.2, and 1.8.1 and 1.8.0
With 1.7.2 jscrollPane works correctly